# use location.hash to keep page status in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, hash, location

I am doing a practice that use location.hash to keep page's state, what i have done using the below code is

1.click any button, the button's innerHTML will be written into the `div#cont`

2.refresh the page, it keeps the changes in the `div#cont`

```html
<body>
    <button id="a">A</button>
    <button id="b">B</button>
    <button id="c">C</button>
    <div id="cont"></div>
    <script>
    // var hashValue;
    function getHash() {
        var hashValue = location.hash;
        return hashValue;
    }
    function draw() {
        var cont = getHash();
        if (cont) {
            document.getElementById('cont').innerHTML = cont.slice(1);
        }
    }

    btns = document.getElementsByTagName('button');
    for (i = 0; i < btns.length; i++) {
        btns[i].index = i;
        btns[i].onclick = function() {
            location.hash = btns[this.index].innerHTML;   
        }
    }
    window.onhashchange = function() {
        draw();
    }
    draw();
    </script>
</body>
```

And what i want to achieve next is add three other buttons(D,E,F) and a new div, when clicking one of the D\E\F, the innerHTMl will written into the new div.

The final goal is

1. click one of the A\B\C, the value will be written into 'contABC'
2. click one of the D\E\F, the value will be written into 'contDEF'
3. keep the changes when the page refresh

because this time it has to record two value, and i have no idea how to use hash to do that, anyone can help? Thanks in advance!

This is HTML:

```html
    <button id="a">A</button>
    <button id="b">B</button>
    <button id="c">C</button>
    <button id="d">D</button>
    <button id="e">E</button>
    <button id="f">F</button>
    <div id="contABC"></div>
    <div id="contDEF"></div>
```

Comment: Why do you want to use the `window.hash`? I prefer to use the **HTML5 History API**.

Comment: @MohammadRezaKhedri,thanks for your suggerstion, i have read some stuff about html5 history API, what i have found is history.pushstate can do the same thing with location.hash in this situation. But all examples show me pushstate always works with onpopstate, and popstate is usd to monitor if browser go back or forward. so, in my case, should i still use #  as the last parameter for pushstate, and onhashchange to mornitor if url has change, or is there some other way can achieve my case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try by structuring  the way you store the hash value , like using a separator `-`

```
<body>
<button data-attr='ABC' id="a">A</button>
<button data-attr='ABC' id="b">B</button>
<button data-attr='ABC' id="c">C</button>
<button data-attr='DEF' id="d">D</button>
<button data-attr='DEF' id="e">E</button>
<button data-attr='DEF' id="f">F</button>
<div id="contABC"></div>
<div id="contDEF"></div>
<script>
// var hashValue;
function getHash() {
    var hashValue = location.hash && location.hash.slice(1);
    return hashValue && hashValue.split('-');
}
function draw() {
     var cont = getHash();
    if (cont && cont.length>0) {
        document.getElementById('contABC').innerHTML = cont[0];
        document.getElementById('contDEF').innerHTML = cont[1];
    }
}

btns = document.getElementsByTagName('button');
var seperator = '-';
for (i = 0; i < btns.length; i++) {
    btns[i].index = i;
    btns[i].onclick = function() {
        var cont = getHash() || [];
        if(btns[this.index].dataset.attr=='ABC'){
            location.hash = btns[this.index].innerHTML + seperator + cont[1];
        }else{
            location.hash =  cont[0] +  seperator + btns[this.index].innerHTML ;
        }
    }
}
window.onhashchange = function() {
    draw();
}
draw();
</script>
</body>
```